# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in java ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jdbc

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.testdemo.TestFile.main(TestFile.java:13)
```

I have added all required jar files with in the library but results in same error

Comment: Did you add HiveDriver in the class path???

Comment: Yes but it not works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` means that a class is being referenced but not found.

The `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` class is referenced in `com.testdemo.TestFile.main`, but `com.testdemo.TestFile.main` can not find `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`. This is usually caused by they referenced class not being at the referenced location, or on the same layer of the project file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Add the hive-jdbc jar in your class-path.It will resolve your problem.